# How to get current week dates using jquery

Tags: 2013

I am trying to retrieve dates in the present week. Is there a way to do that using jquery? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please refer this link. this will help you out --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210376/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-the-week-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Moment.js to deal with dates. For your case:

```
var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('week').toDate();
var endOfWeek   = moment().endOf('week').toDate();
```

This is just a small use case, it's really simple to do a lot of complex operations.

You can see learn more here: http://momentjs.com/